# NOT typical PHP headers warning

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

I have seen headers warnings before due to HTML or a space or in the file before sending headers. I know to avoid that. I have a file that generates an XML file and I can ***successfully***  set the content-type as XML when I run it *on my localhost*. When I run it on *my production server*, I get the "headers already sent" warning.

My suspicion is that something on the server is running before the file (even though I address the file directly, not as an include). I suspected WordPress so, to hopefully avoid this, I created a subdomain and placed the file there to no avail.

*How can I detect if something is loading before the file on the server?* Does WordPress take over the whole domain, subdomains and all? If so, is there a way to prevent this? I want this to run outside of WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have an `auto_prepend_file` directive in your `php.ini`, but I think it's most likely that you are falling prey to the BOM at the start of your file. You should ensure that your files are being saved as UTF-8 *without* BOM (sometimes referred to as "ANSI as UTF-8"), and ensure that the server is keeping this encoding too.

Comment: Yes, the BOM was the problem. Now I have to work through the XML errors I can now see.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that there's no prepended characters in your script (you have checked for a BOM marker?) then the most likely cause is the webserver is configured to auto-prepend a file - you can verify this by:

```
print ini_get('auto_append_file');
```